# How to properly solve this inequality $2^x < \frac{3}{4}$?

Tags: inequality, logarithms, exponential-function

How to properly solve this inequality? 
$$2^x < \frac{3}{4}$$
I know that it will be something like that: 
$$ x \stackrel{?}{\ldots} \log_2\frac{3}{4} $$
But I don't know how to decide if it should be $>$ or $<$.

Comment: depend on the "less than"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply strictly monotonic increasing functions to both sides of an inequality. This is the case for $\log_2$, so just apply $\log_2$ to both sides.

(A strictly monotonic decreasing function reverses the inequality direction.)

Wikipedia has [an article on monotonicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) if you want to learn more about it.

Comment: Something like $\log_2 2^x < \log_2 \frac 3 4 \iff x < \log_2 \frac 3 4$?

Comment: @tdudzik Your $\LaTeX$ needs work, but that's it exactly.
`\log_2 2^x < \log_2 \frac 3 4 \iff x < \log_2 \frac 3 4`

Comment: @GFauxPas : Calling it $\LaTeX$ rather than MathJax is misleading about the nature of actual $\LaTeX$, most of whose code does not involve mathematical notation. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

You have $$2^x < \frac{3}{4}$$ equivalently$$\ln 2^x < \ln\frac{3}{4}$$ $$x\ln 2 < \ln\frac{3}{4}$$$$x < \frac{\ln\frac{3}{4}}{\ln 2}$$ $$x < \log_2\frac{3}{4}$$ Observe that $\log_2(\cdot)$ is strictly increasing on $x>0$:$$ (\log_2)'(x)=\frac{1}{\ln 2}\frac{1}x>0, \quad x>0.$$

Comment: I think they are asking *how do you know* natural log preserves inequalities...?

Answer (score 1):

I'm expanding on what GFauxPas said about monotonicity, notably how you can say whether a function is monotonic and in which direction:

In general, it's a good idea to sketch the curve of the function (in this case $\log_2 x$) to see whether it's increasing or decreasing (if at all). In this case the curve [looks like this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20log_2%20x%20from%20x%3D%200%20to%202), from which it is clear that it is strictly increasing on $(0, \infty)$, so we have,
$$0 < x < y \implies \log_2 x < \log_2 y$$

Of course, just sketching the curve isn't particularly rigorous, plus this only works if you know the shape of the curve off the top of your head (or if you use a computer). Here are some other ways of justifying this result:

A standard way is using calculus, is to use the fact that if $f'(x) > 0$ for some interval, then the function is strictly increasing on that interval. Since $(\log_2 x)' = 1/(x \ln 2),$ for $x>0$ we can see it is increasing for $x>0$. This method works in general, so it's useful to remember.

Another way is as follows, if $0<x<y,$ then there exists some $n>0$ such that $y = nx.$ Since $x < y = nx,$ it follows that $n>1.$ Then we have,
$$ \log_2 y = \log_2 nx = \log_2 n + \log_2 x > \log_2 x$$
Since $\log_2 n > 0.$ Note that this proof does use the fact that $\log_2 n>0$ if $n>1,$ so you may want to think about why that's true.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: $2^x < 2^{\log_{2}\frac{3}{4}} \iff 2^{x-\log_{2}\frac{3}{4}} < 1$

Answer (score 0):

Generically,
$$x^y<a$$

The sinal will be the same if : $$x>1$$

and the sinal will be the opposite if : $$0<x<1$$

Basically, the sinal will stay the same if you have a strictly monotonic increasing function, and will change when you have a strictly monotonic decreasing function.